# Simple regex redirect not working

Tags: regex, redirect

I'm trying to setup a simple regex redirect. I have the following:

```
^.+?testurl\.com/folder-path/(\w+?$)/secondfolder
```

Which should then redirect to

```
http://www.testurl.com/folder-path/$1
```

This works if I don't add the `/secondfolder` to the end of the regex, but as soon as I add `/secondfolder` it doesn't work so I presume my syntax is wrong. Can anybody shed any light on what is wrong about the `/secondfolder` part of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` denotes the end of the string (while `^` marks the start), so you should put it at the end of the string.

```
^.+?testurl\.com/folder-path/(\w+?)/secondfolder$
```