regex redirect structure for AffiliateWP Plugin
Background of the issue:
I am using WPML and AffiliateWP on my site https://example.com. Initially, the default language was English, and referral links were structured as example.com/ar/forex/username for Arabic and example.com/forex/username for English. After changing the default language to Arabic, the site structure changed to example.com for Arabic and example.com/en for English. The affiliate links now appear as example.com/forex/username for Arabic and example.com/en/forex/username for English.
Symptoms:
I am concerned about the impact on old referral links shared on social media after changing the default language.
Questions:
What will happen to old referral links shared in social media?
Does AffiliateWP still track visits and conversions to WPForms?
What should I do to not lose affiliate links (Old ones)?
I have YoastSEO and it has Regex Redirect function
How to create a regex redirect for this link www.example.com/ar/forex/{username}
to www.example.com/forex/{username}
And how to create  a regex redirect for this link www.example.com/forex/{username}
to www.example.com/en/forex/{username}
Please advice.
Thank you in advanced
I tried online redirect generator and it gave me this code:
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ar/forex/kguru$ https://pfxtrader.com/forex/kguru 
And I found this answer and I tried to use it but couldn't understand how to modify
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21022259/23491627
^.+?testurl\.com/folder-path/(\w+?)/secondfolder$
I tried also:
/https://pfxtrader\\.com/ar/forex/\\*/i

But didn't work

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

@Barmar , its a wordpress question and not a unix question, if you are familier with wordpress Yoast plugin you will get what I mean, it has redirection based on regex strucuture
